# I've been living in vs. I've been in

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the difference between the two sentences:

> 1. I've **been living in** X country for 20 years.
> 2. I've **been in** X country for 20 years.

Is #1 still in the X country? Also, is #2 also still in the X country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both mean you've spent a certain amount of time in the country, but "I've been living in X" implies that you've either moved to X or stayed there for eg. a long term work assignment, while "I've been in X" is more likely to mean a temporary, short stay.

Comment: Hello, regarding #1, is he still in the same country until now? (whether he has moved or has stayed) thx. I need that clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence can be re-written by using Present Perfect.

> **I have been living here for 20 years.** (I want to tell you that it's been a good 20 years since I came here for the first time)
>
> **I have lived here for 20 years.** (I just simply want to tell you that 20 years are gone but I will live here, however)

Despite of different tenses, the two abovementioned sentences mean the same.

What might concern you as the question of whether they are still there is another sentence, but with the verb *gone*.

> **He has been to Budapest.** (He has already been to there and came back)
>
> **He has gone to Budapest.** (He went there but he hasn't come back yet)

Comment: Sry, this is a bit way off.